# Where is the information passed to `custom-set-variables` and `custom-set-faces` stored?

Tags: customize, customization, custom

The post's title pretty much says it all.

In particular, I want to find out what happens if I invoke `custom-set-variables` twice, with completely different arguments each time.  E.g.

```
(custom-set-variables '(this "foo"))
(custom-set-variables '(that "bar"))
```

Does this have the same effect as

```
(custom-set-variables '(this "foo")
                      '(that "bar"))
```

?

And ditto for `custom-set-faces`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both just set the named variables. `custom-set-variables` sets the value of the variable as well as several other properties, while `custom-set-faces` only sets some properties. You can get these using the `symbol-value` and `symbol-plist` functions.

For example:

```
(custom-set-variables '(db48x/test 24 t) '(db48x/test 42 t))
(symbol-value 'db48x/test)
42
(symbol-plist 'db48x/test)
(theme-value ((user 42)) saved-value (42) saved-variable-comment nil force-value t variable-comment nil custom-requests 42)
```

For a face you have this:

```
(symbol-plist 'default)
(face-defface-spec ((t nil)) face-modified nil face 0 face-documentation "Basic default face." event-symbol-element-mask (default 0) event-symbol-elements (default) ...)
```

For more information about how variables get their values, I recommend section 8.1 *Symbol Components* of the ELisp manual. (Use `M-: (info "(elisp) Symbol Components")` to jump right to it.